# postgresql: Restoring database backup is very slow and used resources are underutilized significantly

Tags: database, postgresql, backup, postgresql-14

I am trying to restore backup of postgresql database on my personal computer. My OS is Ubuntu 18 and I use postgresql of 14 version. Volume of .sql file is 52G, but after waiting for 6 hours the volume of target database increased only to 120 MB. Then I changed some parameters of  my default postgres.conf:

```
work_mem = 32MB
shared_buffers = 4GB
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
full_page_writes = off
autovacuum = off
wal_buffers = -1
```

But the speed remained mostly the same.  The resource utilization during INSERTs is following:

- CPU < 7% (ps -aux)
- Memory < 0.5 % (ps -aux)
- Disk write speed < 1000 K/S (iotop, dd reached more than 80 MB/s)

Thank you in advance.
Command used here is  sudo -u postgres psql lom < psql_long_small_dump

Comment: You mention INSERTs, did you do the `pg_dump` with either `--inserts` or `--column-inserts`? If that is the case it will definitely slow down the restore.

Comment: I didn't create this backup, but I can ask its creator if necessary. But it is not now, the answer below seems to increase performance dramatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`psql` will restore the dump in a single thread (mostly, `CREATE INDEX` can get parallelized), so you won't exhaust your resources that way. You'd have more luck with a custom format dump (`pg_dump -F c`) which you can restore in several threads with `pg_restore -j 4` or so.

The parameters you change seem random. To speed up your current restore process as much as you can, set the following:

```
wal_level = minimal  # requires a restart
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
max_wal_size = 20GB  # as big as you want
```

and restore using `psql -1` so that everything runs in a single transaction.

Comment: Thank you! Performance increased dramatically. CPU utilization is 80% now!  I copied your steps except custom dump format.

Comment: How to use psql -1 in pgadmin?

Comment: @keramat You cannot. `psql` is a different interactive client from pgAdmin.